# Open Character Viewer for emoji and symbols using external keyboard

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I use my MacBook mostly docked, and with an external keyboard. Using the shortcut <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> you can open the Character Viewer, however for me **this only works on the MacBook keyboard**, not using the external (third-party) keyboard. I have this problem on two different keyboards! However, the command key works (I can use <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> in my terminal just fine) and <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> launches Spotlight Search.

What is the problem here? I'm using Monterey.

Comment: What about [globe key]+E?